# VLC live stream to html5 video

Tags: streaming, html5-video, vlc, rtsp, live-streaming

My requirement is to display live cam RTSP streaming on webpage. I use VLC to restream rtsp to http.

Following is the command I use to restram

```
vlc -vvv rtsp://mycam.com/myvideo/vid2 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=mp4v,acodec=mpga,vb=800,ab=128,deinterlace}:duplicate{dst=display,dst=http{mux=ts,dst=0.0.0.0:8082,sdp=sap,name="tt"}}'
```

And following is the html code I used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</head>
<body>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="http://127.0.0.1:8082/vid.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
    </video>
</body>
</html>
```

Not working on Crome and firefox. Also tried .ogg format.

Please help.

Comment: I don't think you can create a real-time fragmented MP4 stream with VLC (non-fragmented won't work unless you fall back to HLS, Smooth Streaming or other playlist based format). Try ffmpeg.

Comment: VLC 2.2 and later actually include a httplive access-output so you can use it to create an HLS stream and have it served through ngnix or apache. However, this is not what is done in the command line above.

Comment: @feepk  Thanks feepk, can you please add any reference url on it?